# How to solve $x^2 - ny - 2 = 0$ for integer solutions, with different coefficients of $y$?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, quadratics, quadratic-forms

$$x^2 - ny - 2 = 0, n \in Z$$

I put this equation in wolframalpha, and got **integer solutions** for random n = [7](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+7+y+-+2+%3D+0), [23](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+23+y+-+2+%3D+0), 31, 47, 49, 71, 73, 343.

for n = 7 it gave the integer solutions as $$x = 7 n + 3, y = 7 n^2 + 6 n + 1, n \in Z$$
$$x = 7 n + 4, y = 7 n^2 + 8 n + 2, n \in Z$$

and for n = 23 it gave the integer solutions as $$x = 23 n + 5, y = 23 n^2 + 10 n + 1, n \in Z $$
$$x = 23 n + 18, y = 23 n^2 + 36 n + 14, n \in Z $$

It was noteworthy that the **sum of free numbers in x is always equal to n (i.e. coefficient of y)**. 7 had 3 and 4 as free-x-values, 23 had 5 and 18 as free-x-values, and so on. So, as we can see, those free-x-values are always smaller than n.

For some values (like even numbers) there weren't any solutions shown, So I guess there weren't any. But as most of these have only 2 integer solutions, some had 4 integer solutions, like 511 for an example, which had 2 pairs of free-x-values, adding  to 511.

**My question is, how do I determine if the equation has only exactly 2 solutions, or more than 2 solutions, for a given value of n (i.e. coefficient of y)?**

I'm not particularly concerned with the solutions themselves, just that the number of solutions is just 2 or more than that. I can't try values one by one, as the coefficient of y can get large. Wolfram isn't (understandably) handling that big numbers, so I'm trying to write code to solve these equations, but as I don't know what is going on behind the scenes, I can't do anything.

Also, let's say **if I find the 1st (smallest) solution, and the 4th (as their sum is predetermined). Can I use them to find the other two (2nd and 3rd) solutions, if they exist?**

I looked into Diophantine equations of degree two, but the examples I found had all variables of second degree in them. So, I'm not sure if it qualifies for that. If if still does, please let me know.
I tried to solve the equation as a quadratic equation, but got stumped as the coefficient of $y^2$ is 0.

My mathematical background is only upto basic highschool level. So, if I need to study some field(s), to be able to solve this, please guide me, as I'm willing to study to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't you mean $\equiv$ instead of $=$?

Comment: You would want to become familiar with modular arithmetic and quadratic residues. Your question is basically asking "when is $2$ a quadratic residue modulo $n$?". This has a very exact answer when $n$ is prime (the law of quadratic reciprocity), and from primes we can find a result for all $n$.

Comment: As radekzak said, a set of integer solutions is available when $\space n=p^q\space $, a prime number to any positive power $\space q\space $ where $\space p\equiv \pm1\mod 8\qquad$
 Under $100,\space p\in\{7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97\}$


The number of solutions is twice the number of prime factors of $\space n.\quad$


Aside, there are also solutions for $n=1$ and $n=2$

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm not very sure about usage of that sign, so I used what I actually used.

Comment: @jlammy, Thank you. I will look into those subjects. When you say "from primes we can find a result for all n". Do you mean we will only know the answer if only input primes?

Comment: @poetasis, Thank you. For example, 7 has 2 prime factors,  1 and 17. So, it should have 4 solutions. Or is 1 not considered a prime factor?

Comment: @rohitanshu All primes have only themselves and $1$ as factors but $1$ is not a prime number according to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmentic. All of these primes have $2$ infinities of solution $\space \big(m\in\mathbb{Z}\big)\quad$ None have $4$ as far as I know unless $n$ is the product of $2$ primes.

Comment: @poetasis I'm sorry if I'm bothering you, my example 511 has 4 factors, 1, 7, 73 and 511. If we disregard 1, then it should  have 3*2 = 6 solutions, but it only has 4!
Also, 49 has 2 factors 7 and 7, so I think they have to be distinct prime factors as well?

Comment: That sign means modular congruence. It basically means two numbers have the same remainder. Example, 2 $\equiv$ 6 in modulus 2. I assumed you meant modular congruence instead of equal, because otherwise your equation would be finding what quadratics have integer roots @rohitanshu

Comment: @SomeGuy, Thank you.

Comment: So is it supposed to be a modular congruence or not? You may want to correct that if it is

Comment: @rohitanshu Forget the $1$ and $n$ factors. Each $n$ has $\space 2(2^{k-1})\space $ solutions where $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of  $n.\quad $ For example, $2737=7*17*23\space $ has $2(2^{3-1})=8\space$ solutions. Oddly, if we have $2$ as a factor, the numbers are sometimes different. e.g. $2$ has $1,\;2p$ has $2,\;2p_1p_2\space$ has $4,\;$ and  $2p_1p_2p_3 \;$ has $5,\;2p_1p_2p_3p_4 \;$ has $10$ but $p_1p_2p_3p_4 $ has $16$ solutions. If we confine ourselves to the primes listed earlier, the formula above works every time.

Comment: @SomeGuy, I meant to find the integer roots for quadratics. But people here have showed that my question falls under modular arithmetic and quadratic residues, and is related to prime numbers. So, I think I should leave it as an equal sign as the original question I had. But if you think ≡ sign must be used instead, feel free to edit the question. :)

Comment: Yes. Can't we write $2(2^{k−1})$ as $2^k$ though? Please also see my [this comment] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008685/how-to-solve-x2-ny-2-0-for-integer-solutions-with-different-coefficien#comment8274929_4008737)

Comment: @rohitanshu I made the same mistake with $2*7*17*23$ before I noticed the was a "more solutions" button to the upper right of the solutions listing. There are 8 solutions if you click. You are right about spotting $2^k$.

Comment: @poetasis Haha, that was a silly mistake on my part. Thank you for being so patient with me though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you would have $n|x^2-2$, then putting $y = \frac{x^2-2}{2}$ gives us a legitimate solution. So we only need to be worried about solutions to that divisibility.

You can easily see, that if $x$ is a solution, then $n-x$ and $n+x$ are also solutions. That yields your observation with summing up to $n$.

Now we will focus on the set $S$ of such $n$, that some solution exists.

If $k$ and $l$ are coprime numbers in $S$, then using Chinese Remainder Theorem we can find solution for $kl$. Moreover, the number of solutions for $kl$ will be equal to the product of these numbers for $k$ and $l$. We also see quite obviously that if $n \in S$, then all divisors of $n$ are in $S$.

From these two facts, we only need to be worried about $n$ equal to prime powers. It is not very easy to prove that $n=p^k$ works iff $n=2$ or $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$, but you should be able to find proof of this fact in any materials about quadratic residues (here, for example, $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $n$, since $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod n$).

So, solutions exist for $n$ iff all of its prime divisors are $2$ or primes $\equiv 1$ or $7 \pmod 8$, where $2$ can show up only once (so $n$ can't be divisible by $4$, but it can be even). Number of these solutions (or, to be exact, number of different families of sulutions modulo $n$) is equal to $2^k$, where $k$ is number of distinct odd prime divisors of $n$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, I forgot about that case.

Comment: So, the only way to know the number of integer solutions is to factorize n first? Is that correct?

Comment: Also, 32767 has 4 prime factors, 7, 31 and 151, so it should have $2^3 = 8$ solutions, but wolframalpha is showing only 5 to me? Is it not calculating all of them?

Comment: @rohitanshu Yes, you need to factorize n.

For 32767, I guess that WolframAlpha just doesn't show some solutions.

Comment: Then that answers my original question about number of solutions. I'm accepting your answer. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Just a heads up, I found out that WolframAlpha does show all the solutions as pointed out by @poetasis, it's just hidden under 'more solutiions' button.